# Linear Transformations and Matrix Representation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

- L be the transformation with matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

  a) Find the image of the line along $\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ under $L$.

  b) Find the image of the line along $\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix}$ under $L$.

My solution-trying:

for a) $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ $\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ becomes $\begin{pmatrix}  7 \\ -3 \end{pmatrix}$. It's solution for question $a)$.

**Can you check my answer? If it is false, can you help, can you give a hint?**

Comment: The line along the first vector $v$ is the set $\{ \lambda v \}$, where $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ is a scalar. Your answer should therefore be a set, not a matrix.

Comment: @leibnewtz How should I do?

Comment: Also, you're multiplying matrices and vectors incorrectly. http://mathinsight.org/matrix_vector_multiplication

Comment: @Kahler Make sure you understand how to multiply vectors by matrices correctly, and then do that for each vector in the line.

Comment: @leibnewtz Edited for multiplyng matrces. Can you check now?

Comment: @erfink Edted for multiplying matrices. Can you check now?

Comment: You did not multiply the vector by the matrix correctly. Check it again and think about the first comment above.

Comment: @Paul Edited for multiplyng matrces. Can you check now?

Comment: @leibnewtz How can I get your first comment (as answer is for a set)?

Comment: I'm waiting a comment/ an answer. Please...

Comment: All scalar multiples of this product IS your line of points.

Comment: @Paul What is the IS mean?

Comment: @Paul My answer is true?

Comment: The line along the vector $v$ is the set $\{\lambda v : \lambda \in \Bbb{R}\} = \{\begin{pmatrix}3\lambda \\ \lambda \end{pmatrix} : \lambda \in \Bbb{R}\}$. So what you have to do is take the general vector from this set, and look at its image. The answer will the be the set of all images, i.e. $\{ \text{image of standard vector} : \lambda \in \Bbb{R}\}$.

Comment: @AlgTop Then, I should do $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ $\begin{pmatrix} 3\lambda \\ \lambda \end{pmatrix}$, right? Hence, we get answer for question?

Comment: Exactly! And then take the set of all such vectors and $\lambda$ varies

Comment: @AlgTop Ohh... THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the underlying field here is $\mathbb{R}$. Every $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$ may be viewed as a linear transformation $A: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$. Now let $v \in \mathbb{R}^2$ be a nonzero vector. Since $v \neq 0$, $L=span\{v\} \cong \mathbb{R}$ is a line in (or one dimensional subspace of) $\mathbb{R}^2$. Its image under $A$ is just its image as a set under $A$, i.e. $A(L)= \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 | \exists \lambda \in \mathbb{R} \; \text{such that} \;  x= A(\lambda v)\}$.

Since $A$ is linear, the condition $x=A(\lambda v)$ is the same as $x= \lambda A(v)$, so once we find the image of $v$, we're essentially done. However, it's important to keep in mind that finding $A(L)$ *is not the same thing* as finding $A(v)$.

Do you see what computations you have to make and why?

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I don't see.